# Error converting data type nvarchar to datetime2 in Java

Tags: java, sql-server

I am calling one MSSQL procedure from spring storedprocedure.execute method. I tried passing date parameter as java.sql.Date , java.sql.Timestamp and pure string as well, but with all the options it gives same error "Error converting data type nvarchar to datetime2" 
here is the syntax of my proc

```
  PROCEDURE [sampleProc]
@errorMsg           VARCHAR(MAX) OUTPUT
,@startDate         DATETIME     = NULL
,@endDate           DATETIME     = NULL
,@par1      VARCHAR(200) = NULL
,@par2              VARCHAR(200) = NULL
,@par3          VARCHAR(200) = NULL
```

Java code which call it :

```
Map<String, Object> results = super.execute(errMsg,convertJavaDateToSql   (startDate),convertJavaDateToSql(endDate),null,null,null);
```

and convertJavaDateToSql method is

```
 Timestamp convertJavaDateToSql(String date){
            Date javaDate = null;
            try {
                javaDate =  dateFormat.parse(date);
                logger.info("Parsed Date is "+javaDate );
            } catch (ParseException e) {

                logger.error("Error Parsing startDate and endDate" );
            }

            if(javaDate!=null) {
                Timestamp sqlDateTime = new Timestamp(javaDate.getTime());
                logger.info("sql Date  "+sqlDateTime);
                return sqlDateTime;
            }else
                return null;
        }
```

and this is how I declare parameter

```
declareParameter(new SqlReturnResultSet("RESULT_LIST",
                    myDataExtractor));
            declareParameter(new SqlOutParameter("errorMsg",Types.VARCHAR));
    declareParameter(new SqlParameter("startDate",Types.TIMESTAMP));
    declareParameter(new SqlParameter("endDate", Types.TIMESTAMP));
    declareParameter(new SqlParameter("par1",Types.VARCHAR));
    declareParameter(new SqlParameter("par2", Types.VARCHAR));
    declareParameter(new SqlParameter("par3",Types.VARCHAR));
```

Here is the error log

```
   org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: CallableStatementCallback; SQL [{call sampleProc(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)}Error converting data type nvarchar to datetime2.; nested exception is com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Error converting data type nvarchar to datetime2.
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.doTranslate(SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.java:247)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:72)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.translateException(JdbcTemplate.java:1400)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:1063)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.call(JdbcTemplate.java:1102)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.object.StoredProcedure.execute(StoredProcedure.java:122)
```

I found many question on this site with same title but none helped with java code.Could anyone please help me on this.
Thanks

Comment: please attach the error logs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have resolved the issue. Issue was that storedProcedure.execute doesn't maintain parameter order so it was setting date value in another nvarchar field.
I am passing a map now with  field name and value in execute method and it works.

```
  Map<String,Object> inParameters = new HashMap<>();
                //Its a mandatory field , so passing it as null.
                inParameters.put(DAOConstants.ERROR_MSG, null);
                inParameters.put(DAOConstants.START_DATE, converJavaToSqlDate(startDate));
                inParameters.put(DAOConstants.END_DATE, converJavaToSqlDate(endDate));
                inParameters.put(DAOConstants.PARAM1, par1);
                inParameters.put(DAOConstants.PARAM2, par2);
                inParameters.put(DAOConstants.PARAM3, par3);

                Map<String, Object> results = super.execute(inParameters);
```